# Following mouse with acceleration and deceleration

Tags: algorithm

I'm making an object which always faces mouse position with smooth transition - acceleration and deceleration.

For decelerating near mouse it's an easy equation:

```
rotation += deltaRotation / speed
```

For accelerating there's a little more code (but it wobbles around target rotation, as there's no friction or damping)

```
var deltaRotation = rotation - targetRotation;

if (Math.abs(deltaRotation) < EPSILON) { //Stop motion near 0
    return;
}

var direction = deltaRotation != 0 ? deltaRotation / Math.abs(deltaRotation) : 0;

dv += ACCELERATION * direction * dt;

dv = FMath.clamp(dv, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED);

rotation += dv * deltaRotation;
```

How to merge these both algorithms, so the rotation will slowly start and slowly reach target rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the physical world, the acceleration is proportional to force applied.  One way to model the force applied at a given time step is to make it proportional to distance you need to object to move, minus some damping force.  The damping force (like friction or wind resistance) is in the opposite direction of and proportional to the current velocity.  The damping force effectively limits the top speed and gives a nice deceleration as the direct force drops off.

Consider a linear system.  Let's say `xCursor` is the position of the cursor, and `xMonster` is the position of the thing chasing the cursor.  Let's use `dxMonster` for the monster's velocity.

First we need to know how far away we are, because we want to accelerate the monster according to that.

```
float delta = xCursor - xMonster;
```

`force` is the net force.  It includes a direct force that accelerates the monster toward the cursor and a damping force that resists the monster's current velocity.

```
float force = A*delta - B*dxMonster;
```

You can play with the constants to see what works best.  You probably want `A < B`.  In my test program, I used `A = 0.1` and `B = 0.5`.

Since acceleration is proportional to force, we can add it directly to the velocity.  Note that we no longer need to clamp the velocity, since the damping force will keep it from growing too large.  The velocity is then used to update the position.  (In a better simulation, you can approximate this better using something like Runge-Kutta to do the integration, but simply adding at each time step is fine for a simple animation.)

```
dxMonster += force;
xMonster += dxMonster;
```

Repeat for each timestep.  I omitted the `dt`s because my frame rate was stable enough that it didn't matter much.

Your problem is about rotation rather than linear motion, but that's completely analogous.  In physical terms, it's just angular velocity and torque rather than linear velocity and force.

Comment: Thanks! This is just a cosmetic detail in my game so no need for overkill. I'm using RK4/some Verlet derivative (or whatever else Nape phys engine uses) for important game elements. I'll accept your answer when I can